# IllegalStateException on startup of ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am struggling to run ActiveMQ on Windows. When I navigate to the ActiveMQ `bin` directory  and run `.\activemq.bat start`, I get the following exception:

```
2022-02-16 10:16:33,900 | WARN  | Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@611889f4: startup date [Wed Feb 16 10:16:32 MST 2022]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057)[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook.run(SpringContextHook.java:30)[activemq-spring-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.stop(BrokerService.java:809)[activemq-broker-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.stop(XBeanBrokerService.java:122)[activemq-spring-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:601)[activemq-broker-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.afterPropertiesSet(XBeanBrokerService.java:73)[activemq-spring-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)[:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1638)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)[xbean-spring-3.16.jar:3.16]
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)[xbean-spring-3.16.jar:3.16]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67)[activemq-spring-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)[activemq-broker-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)[activemq-broker-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:87)[activemq-console-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)[activemq-console-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:150)[activemq-console-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)[activemq-console-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)[activemq-console-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)[:]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)[activemq.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)[activemq.jar:5.10.0]
```

I am using ActiveMQ version 5.10.0 on a Java 8 JDK. I also tried with Java 11 and the result was the same.

How can I fix this? I'm not even sure where to start.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to move to a more recent version of ActiveMQ. Version 5.10.0 was released way back in June 2014 almost 8 years ago at this point. The [latest release is 5.16.4](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/). You might also consider upgrading all the way to [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/), the next generation broker from ActiveMQ. The latest release of ActiveMQ Artemis is [here](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/).

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely incompatible JDK+Spring+ActiveMQ. Try upgrading to ActiveMQ 5.16.4 with JDK 11.